# sending user-initiated email via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, soap-api, soap

I have a user-initiated email send definition set up in SFMC.  Which API endpoint or customized envelope do I use to initiate an actual send-out using that send definition?

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be appreciated to know how to better ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure if you NEED to do this by objectId, but it is the safest bet in any case.

For scheduling:

POST `yourSoapEndpoint + "Service.asmx"`

Headers:

`contentType = 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8;'`

`SOAPAction: "Schedule"`

payload

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
       <fueloauth>{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ScheduleRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Action>start</Action>
        <Schedule>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <Recurrence xsi:type="q1:DailyRecurrence" xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <q1:DailyRecurrencePatternType>Interval</q1:DailyRecurrencePatternType>
                <q1:DayInterval>1</q1:DayInterval>
            </Recurrence>
            <RecurrenceType>Daily</RecurrenceType>
            <RecurrenceRangeType>EndAfter</RecurrenceRangeType>
            <StartDateTime>{{sendTime}}</StartDateTime>
            <Occurrences>1</Occurrences>
        </Schedule>
        <Interactions>
            <Interaction xsi:type="q2:EmailSendDefinition" xmlns:q2="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <q2:PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <q2:ObjectID>{{userInitiatedSendDefinitionObjectId}}</q2:ObjectID>
            </Interaction>
        </Interactions>
    </ScheduleRequestMsg>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

for sending now:

You can actually use WSProxy (which does not support the "schedule" SOAPACtion it seems...so no WSProxy for the above).

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var action = "Start";
        var props = {
             ObjectID: sendDefinitionObjId
             ,DeduplicateByEmail: true
        };

        try {
            var performResponse = prox.performItem("EmailSendDefinition", props, action);
            outputObj.status = "ok"
            outputObj.performResponse = Stringify(performResponse)
        
        } catch(e) {
            outputObj.status = "error"
            outputObj.performResponse = Stringify(performResponse) + Stringify(e) + Stringify(props) + action
        }
```

if you need this as an old fashioned SOAP request, you can construct a PerformRequest to the same effect.

POST `yourSoapEndpoint + "Service.asmx"`

Headers:

`contentType = 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8;'`

`SOAPAction: "Perform"`

```
<!--omitted the header, copy from above-->
....
     <PerformRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Action>start</Action>
         <Definitions>
            <Definition xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">
               <ObjectID>{{userInitiatedSendDefinitionObjectId}}</ObjectID>
            </Definition>
         </Definitions>
      </PerformRequestMsg>
    ....
<!--omitted the closing body tag-->
```

Comment: I feel like you're steering me in the right track so thank you so much!  I used the PerformRequest SOAP request for sending immediately and got back this status message in the returned envelope: "Exception occurred during [Schedule::Start] ErrorID = 815021854"  Not a very descriptive or helpful error message.  :(

Comment: I renamed the ObjectID node to CustomerKey and that allowed me to progress (onto the next error I'm dealing with about validation).